# synthesis difference between the two almost identical procedural assignment

Tags: fpga, verilog, hardware, synthesis

I have the following 2 procedure assignment blocks that perform very similar jobs.

first one

```
reg s, i;
reg out;
always @(*)
begin
   out = 0;
   if (s) out = i;
end
```

second one

```
reg s, i;
reg out;
always @(*)
begin
   if (s) out = i;
    else out = 0; 
end
```

They both seem synthesizable to me (and produce no latch) but the second one is clearly a mux, the first seems to be more than mux in that even an ? or x value for s signal will makes signal out to have a zero value... what would the synthesized circuit for the first one be like?

Comment: Did you try it? What is the outcome of a synthesizer run?

Comment: i don't have  a synthesis tool installed atm

Comment: That's easier to fix than to write an answer; install yosys or yoWASP and synthesize away! In fact, you cab run yosys in your browser: http://www.clifford.at/yosys/nogit/YosysJS/snapshot/demo02.html

Comment: Remember that real logic doesn't deal with ? or X input values, so the logic is designed assuming only 0 or 1 inputs.

Comment: Actually, because of the way the Verilog language is defined, both examples express *exactly* the same functionality. If any simulation or synthesis tool gives different results for the two inputs, it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that there are many ways to express the exact same functional behavior in [verilog](/questions/tagged/verilog) or any other [hdl](/questions/tagged/hdl). The job of a synthesis tool is to convert that HDL into a set of Boolean equations and state assignments. It will reduce those equations to an optimal form and the end result *should* be the same.

Simulation has to execute the code the way it is written and can only make certain guarantees about its behavior with respect to other concurrent processes. For example it's possible to have `1→0→1` transition on `out` using the first example. The simulation cannot guarantee if the `0` glitch will be seen or not by other processes.

BTW, synthesis tools do not interpret X values on signals, they are only used in literals for *don't care* expressions. In simulation, if `s` is X, both examples produce a 0 on `out`.